# Can an entity's sub entity could be selected?

Tags: entity, eyeshot

I created several entities and add the block reference of them to another entity. And then I will rotate and translate the parent entity. But I want to use mouse to select those sub entities added to this as a block reference to get the selected entity data. How?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set:
 `model1.AssemblySelectionMode = assemblySelectionType.Leaf;`